# Finding a function from Library

Tags: coq

I want to use function which finds maximum value of the list(list_max_le).
Plz help me in finding the Coq script against this function.Might be I am using old version of Coq.

Comment: `fold_right max 0.`

Comment: [`list_max_le` doesn't find the maximum of a list.](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html#list_max_le) It is a proof about [`list_max`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html#list_max), which has the definition @larsr gave.

Comment: I can esteblish any relation between count of natural number and list_max value?